# Laravel upgrade advice

Tags: laravel, laravel-upgrade

I have an old project with laravel 5.8;
I've tried to update to 6 & 7 & 8, no luck.
I just want to know where to start from. Right now, all i'm doing is changing versions of different packages...Should i remove any lines or what? What all ways do you upgrade a really old project?

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "aporat/store-receipt-validator": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.0",
    "chumper/zipper": "1.0.x",
    "doctrine/cache": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~3.1",
    "mariuzzo/laravel-js-localization": "^1.4",
    "piwik/device-detector": "^3.9",
    "spatie/pdf-to-image": "^1.5",
    "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Weltwoche\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]

},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

Comment: first backup your laravel 5.8 project… second fresh install laravel 6.* in your machine. then copy your app , resource , routes and then fire command
 `composer install`
if any error than solve one by one

Comment: You need to read [the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade) and change any code that is not compatible with laravel 6

Comment: Try using `Laravel Shift` service. https://laravelshift.com/

Comment: Just a side note: upgrading to new laravel versions can break a lot of things so make sure you read the official laravel docs

Comment: Found a blog post regarding this upgrade.. might be worth taking a look https://arobs.com/blog/my-experience-upgrading-laravel-framework-5-8-to-8-x/